# Simplify jQuery variables into a looped function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am pretty new to jQuery and I am trying to find the most practical way to solve my problem. Currently what I have works, however I know I could simplify it and make it more practical. I am just not sure how to.

**So here is my jQuery ...**

```
var hl1 = data.headlines[0,0].headline;
var hl2 = data.headlines[0,1].headline;
var hl3 = data.headlines[0,2].headline;
var hl4 = data.headlines[0,3].headline;
var hl5 = data.headlines[0,4].headline;
var hl6 = data.headlines[0,5].headline;
var hl7 = data.headlines[0,6].headline;
var hl8 = data.headlines[0,7].headline;
var hl9 = data.headlines[0,8].headline;
var hl10 = data.headlines[0,9].headline;

$('#headlines .title').eq(0).append(hl1);
$('#headlines .title').eq(1).append(hl2);
$('#headlines .title').eq(2).append(hl3);
$('#headlines .title').eq(3).append(hl4);
$('#headlines .title').eq(4).append(hl5);
$('#headlines .title').eq(5).append(hl6);
$('#headlines .title').eq(6).append(hl7);
$('#headlines .title').eq(7).append(hl8);
$('#headlines .title').eq(8).append(hl9);
$('#headlines .title').eq(9).append(hl10);
```

And here is my HTML...

```
<div id="headlines">
   <h2 class="title"></h2>
   <h2 class="title"></h2>
   <h2 class="title"></h2>
   <h2 class="title"></h2>
   <h2 class="title"></h2>
   <h2 class="title"></h2>
   <h2 class="title"></h2>
   <h2 class="title"></h2>
</div>
```

So basically what I am doing is pulling some data via AJAX/JSON and appending it into these h2 tags. This works the way I want to however I feel like this could be compressed into one function, but I am not really sure how to get there. Any examples or descriptive help would be very much appreciated. Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the good ol' fashioned `for` loop:

```
var titles = $('#headlines .title');
for (var i=0; i<titles.length; i++)
    titles.eq(i).append(data.headlines[0,i].headline);
```

***Explained:***
[`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) is the most basic form of Javascript iteration.

First I'm caching the `$('#headlines .title')` jQuery selector in the `titles` var, this way I can access all of the matched elements by the `$('#headlines .title')` selector without having to create a new jQuery object for each iteration, which provides a good performance boost.

Next, I iterate through all matched elements, that is, from index 0 (first element) until the last element (that is, `titles.length-1`, as index is [0-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering#In_computer_programming)). The `i<titles.length` part would be the same as `i<=titles.length-1` as I'm using integers, so I chose the one which looks more tidier and has better performance.

Note that the jQuery objects' `.length` property returns the same value as the [`.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/) method, but `.length` is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call, as per [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/size/).

The rest of this part is self-explanatory, the [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method filters the `titles` selector returning only the item with the index which I'm iterating at the moment, this way I can append the `data.headlines` with the very same index to it with the `data.headlines[0,i].headline`.

Or with jQuery [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) iteration:

```
$('#headlines .title').each(function(i) {
    $(this).append(data.headlines[0,i].headline);
}
```

The `.each` jQuery method is very self-explanatory as well, taken from the jQuery API site:

> ***Description:*** Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

So I create a set of DOM elements with the `$('#headlines .title')` and iterate through them with the `.each`. The function passed as parameter will be executed for each element matched by the selector, so, I create a jQuery object with the current element in the iteration - `$(this)` - and append the corresponding headline index to it. `.each`'s index is 0-based, as well as virtually all indexed array(-like) structures in JS.

Comment: This works perfectly thanks... One more request though.I get where most of this is coming from, but would mind breaking down/ explaining the logic of each one to me?

Comment: There isn't much logic, but I'll do my best. Give me a couple mins to write the explanations. `:)`

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck I made 2 explanations, I hope I didn't complicate things too much. I have this bad habit of explaining stuff in too much detail sometimes, just say if you need explanation of a specific area of the code or method or statement. `=]`

Comment: Matte... It is pretty clear. Good explanation. You are very helpful. Thanks. This is something I need to do quite often so I will reference this post if I ever forget how to do it.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck Yes, Wikipedia also has a nice page on [for loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#C) (javascript uses C-style `for loops`, as you can note by my MDN link in the answer as well), iteration is undoubtedly the right arm of any programmer/developer and harnessing it brings a great benefit, making your code cleaner, more concise and much easier to maintain.